# Counter through embedded if statements inside for loop

Tags: python, python-2.7

So, I have a script in python (2.7) that makes a list of 1000000 numbers between 1 and 5000 and then runs a for loop over the entire list checking each element against multiple embedded if statments.

ex:

```
i = 0
for number in random_list:
    i += 1
    if random_list[number] <= 3000:
        i += 1
        if random_list[number] <= 300:
            i += 1
            if random_list[number] <= 30:
                i += 1
                if random_list [number] <= 3:
                    i += 1
                    break
print i
```

the whole point being I want to see how many "checks" occur over the entire list.

unfortunately my i value is less than the total number of elements in the list which should not be the case since each element should be checked at least once. I'm getting something in the range of 1000's to 10000's.

I'm sure there's a more pythonic way of doing this, so any advice on how to achieve what I'm trying will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're doing `for numbers in random_list` but you probably want to do `for numberin random_list` and then `if number <= 3000: ...`. At the moment you're indexing by `number`, which isn't actually defined in your code... Also, why have you got the `break` statement there?

Comment: I think cause he is done once he encounters a value < 3 ... I guess at least

Comment: I had it set as number, not numbers in my code, I just made a mistake >_>

and yes, the reason for the break is stopping once a number is < 3, I always forget if python needs that final break or not, I'm pretty rusty on my python unfortunately

However you are correct that I should be using number not random_list[number].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
extra = 0
values = (random_list[number] for i,number in enumerate(my_numbers))
for v in values:    
    extra += sum(v < x for x in [3000,300,30,3])
    if v < 3:break;

print i+extra
```

maybe ...

Comment: This worked as well. Definitely way more elegant than my original code!